# Dataweave filtering array by another array values

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I would like to filter an array based on another array values. I would like to filter the input array based on key value "KNVP-PARVW" is in the list of ["BP,SH,PY"]

here is the input:

```
[{
    "KNVP-KUNNR": "100098",
    "KNVP-VTWEG": "A1",
    "KNVP-PARVW": "BP",
    "KNVP-PARZA": "000",
    "KNVP-KUNN2": "200115",
    "KNVP-DEFPA": ""
  },
  {
    "KNVP-KUNNR": "100098",
    "KNVP-VTWEG": "A1",
    "KNVP-PARVW": "SH",
    "KNVP-PARZA": "001",
    "KNVP-KUNN2": "200115",
    "KNVP-DEFPA": ""
  },
  {
    "KNVP-KUNNR": "100098",
    "KNVP-VTWEG": "A1",
    "KNVP-PARVW": "ZR",
    "KNVP-PARZA": "000",
    "KNVP-KUNN2": "256",
    "KNVP-DEFPA": ""
  }]
```

and here is my dataweave code:

```
%dw 2.0
var relationList=["BP,SH,PY"]
output application/json
---
payload filter (  relationList contains  $."KNVP-PARVW" )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `["BP,SH,PY"]` is a list, it has only one element which is a string. To use [contains()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-contains) as you intend, it has to be a list of the valid values for `$."KNVP-PARVW"`:

```
%dw 2.0
var relationList=["BP","SH","PY"]
output application/json
---
payload filter (  relationList contains  $."KNVP-PARVW" )
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "KNVP-KUNNR": "100098",
    "KNVP-VTWEG": "A1",
    "KNVP-PARVW": "BP",
    "KNVP-PARZA": "000",
    "KNVP-KUNN2": "200115",
    "KNVP-DEFPA": ""
  },
  {
    "KNVP-KUNNR": "100098",
    "KNVP-VTWEG": "A1",
    "KNVP-PARVW": "SH",
    "KNVP-PARZA": "001",
    "KNVP-KUNN2": "200115",
    "KNVP-DEFPA": ""
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it the var relationList should be like below

```
var relationList="BP,SH,PY"
```

Comment: That is a bad solution. You are using contains() with a string, so if $."KNVP-PARVW"  == "P,S" then it would be true because it is a valid substring of relationList.